# Create a single image from images array

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

Hi I'm trying to create a single image from multiple images in opencv. 
images I use are the same size.

what I do is reshaping them to single line and then try to merge them together with my new image.

I create new image with size of 2 images and pass the array but I recieve error EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address = ..)

note: sizes of images are correct
size of single image : [170569 x 1]
size of new_image    : [170569 x 2]

my code is below.
thank you

```
int main(){


    Mat image[2];
    image[0]= imread("image1.jpg",0);

    image[1]= imread("image2.jpg",0);



   image[0] = image[0].reshape(0, 1); //SINGLE LINE
   image[1] = image[1].reshape(0, 1); //SINGLE LINE

   int size = sizeof(image)/sizeof(Mat);


    Mat new_image(image[0].cols,size,CV_32FC1,image); 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well than you need to concatenate 2 image of same size into one Mat. I wrote this a very quick code to perform this task.

U can change the argument to the function to be a pointer and add other handlers to care about the variant size image.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

cv::Mat cvConcatenateMat(const cv::Mat &image1, const cv::Mat &image2, bool isCol CV_DEFAULT(true)){
if (isCol) {
    cv::Mat mergeMat = cv::Mat(image1.rows, image1.cols + image2.cols, image1.type());
    for (int j = 0; j < image1.rows; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < image1.cols; i++) {
            mergeMat.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) = image1.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);
        }
        for (int i = image1.cols; i < mergeMat.cols; i++) {
            mergeMat.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) = image2.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);
        }
    }
    return mergeMat;
} else {
    cv::Mat mergeMat = cv::Mat(image1.rows + image2.rows, image1.cols, image1.type());
    for (int j = 0; j < image1.cols; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < image1.rows; i++) {
            mergeMat.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = image1.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j);
        }
        for (int i = image1.rows; i < mergeMat.rows; i++) {
            mergeMat.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = image2.at<cv::Vec3b>(i-image1.rows,j);
        }
    }
    return mergeMat;
}
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

cv::Mat image1 = cv::imread("img1.jpg");
cv::Mat image2 = cv::imread("img2.jpg");
cv::resize(image2, image2, image1.size());


cv::Mat outImage = cvConcatenateMat(image1, image2, false);

cv::imshow("out image", outImage);
cv::waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: hi, still I'm recieving the same error. thank you.
in this line of code 
            mergeMat.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) = image2.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);

Comment: I just edited and added the full working code. IT works on my machine without any errors

Comment: hi this concerate them side by side I need them one under the other.

Comment: i have changed the code to perform as u require it.

Comment: hi it adds same image twice instead of merging 2 different

Comment: @Rodrane my apologies I made a small error in line mergeMat.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = image2.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) which should be mergeMat.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = image2.at<cv::Vec3b>(i-image1.rows, j);

Comment: Please see that I added a flag in the function cvConcatenateMat() which takes a true for adding images in column-wise and false for row-wise.

Answer (score 3):

Mat new_image;

vconcat(image[0],image[1],new_image);